# Adding Child Items To Parent With Foreign Key Relationship Prior To Parent Existing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am seeking some guidance on the most appropriate way to tackle this scenario.

If, for example, I want to allow a user to create an Invoice. This invoice has some data which resides in a parent 'invoice' database table and some data which resides in a child 'invoice_lines' database table which is linked to the parent table via a foreign key relationship.

If I want the user to be able to build an invoice on a single screen and allow the user to add an invoice line before the invoice has been created how would I do this without breaking the foreign key relationship?

I.e. if I don't know the id of the parent item how can I add a child item?

Do I create the parent item in the background prior to the invoice building page loading and then I have an id? But, wouldn't this lead to lots of empty incomplete records in my database?

Do I store the invoice lines in local storage and only submit them to the database once the user has submitted the data to create the parent record?

Or none of the above. Is there a go to solution which is considered the best approach for this type of scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Build the invoice and lnvoice_line within a transaction. Then if anything fails nothing will exists, and if everything goes well your have a completed set of data

Comment: If you remember the Invoice should not contain anything that you can work out from the Invoice_lines. Creating the Invoice is a simple process when you create the first invoice_line. So for xample if Invoice contains only `InvNo,Date` that is easily created as part of creating the first line.